# Use jNAOqi with Android

Tags: java, android, shared-libraries, nao-robot

I'm currently working with Aldebaran-Robotics' NAO (v3.3) and I was wondering if I can use the jNAOqi-SDK within Android to control the robot from a phone or tablet.

Using the SDK with basic java in Eclipse was pretty simple as described in [this tutorial](http://www.aldebaran-robotics.com/documentation/dev/java/compiling_examples.html), so I tried to do this in ADT Eclipse. I imported the *.jar-file and placed the precompiled `libjnaoqi.so` from the package in `libs/armeabi` and `libs/armeabi-v7a`, but calling `System.loadLibrary("jnaoqi")` or `System.loadLibrary("<jnaoqi>")` resulted in the following error at runtime:

```
I/dalvikvm(2019): Unable to dlopen(/data/data/com.example.hellonao/lib/libjnaoqi.so): Cannot load library: link_image[1995]: failed to link libjnaoqi.so
```

I checked the filesystem, but the file was in the lib folder as expected, so I guess it has to be a problem with the library itself.

It's just a shot in the dark but do I have to recompile the library using ndk and naoqi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quickly abandoned my project but Aldebaran was busy in the meantime. I recently found a thread about it in the [Aldebaran community (login required)](https://community.aldebaran-robotics.com/forum/thread/android-and-nao/), where two employees (Nicolas Rigaud and Erwan Pinault) mention upcoming Android support.

nrigaud:

> there will be a better Java SDK on our next software version. Meanwhile, it's true that it's not that easy to do Java on the robot

epinault:

> In the next SDK you will have library (jar/so) for android

Comment: there is solution for this? I wanti libjnaogi.so for android

Comment: I don't know, it's been a while and I haven't worked on this since then. But [this post](https://community.ald.softbankrobotics.com/en/forum/using-java-naoqi-sdk-control-nao-android-5347) suggests that there is a way to load the native library into android.